# How Do I show this Map is a Surjective Submersion?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

**Question**

Let $S^2\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ be the 2-sphere, and define $TS^2 = \{(p,v)\in \mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{R}^3|p\in S^2, v\in T_pS^2\}$. It may be regarded as a level set of the function $F:\mathbb{R}^6\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, $F(p,v) = (p.p, p.v)$. Let $M = \{(p,v)\in TS^2|v.v = 1\}$. Show that each of the two maps $H_i:M\rightarrow S^2$ given by $H_1(p,v)=p$, $H_2(p,v)=v$ is a surjective submersion $M\rightarrow S^2$, with fibers diffeomorphic to $S^1$.

**Note**:
There are some sub-questions that precede this. So, I have already shown that $TS^2$ is a 4-dimensional sub-manifold of $\mathbb{R}^6$. I have also shown that $M$ is a 3-dimensional sub-manifold of $\mathbb{R}^6$. For this question, I have shown that $H_1$ is a surjective submersion with fibers diffeormorphic to $S^1$. However, it seems $H_2$ is not surjective. And I can’t show that the fibers are diffeomorphic to $S^1$. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your map $H_2$ is not even well-defined, so no wonder you can't prove anything about it. Where did you get this problem?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I got it from Chapter 5, Question 6, Pg 120, Manifolds, Vector fields, and Differential forms by Gal Gross and Eckhard Meinrenken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove that $M$ is  a 3-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^6$ you certainly considered the smooth map
$$G : \mathbb R^6 \to \mathbb R^3, G(p,v) = (p\cdot p, p \cdot v,  v \cdot v)$$
and showed that $(1,0,1)$ is a regular value of $G$. This implies indeed that $M =  G^{-1}(1,0,1)$  a 3-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^6$. Note that
$$M  = \{ (p,v) \in \mathbb R^6 \mid p, v \in S^2,  p \cdot v = 0 \}. \tag{1}$$

You also proved that $H_1 : M \to S^2$ is a surjective submersion with fibers diffeomorphic to $S^1$.

Now consider $\phi : \mathbb R^6 \to \mathbb R^6, \phi(p,v) = (v,p)$. This is a diffeomorphism. Clearly $\phi(M) = M$ because by (1) for $(p,v) \in \mathbb R^6$ we have $(p,v) \in M$ iff $\phi(p,v) = (v,p) \in M$. Hence $\phi$ restricts to a diffeomorphism $\psi : M \to M$.

Clearly $H_2 = H_1 \circ \psi$, thus $H_2$  a surjective submersion with fibers diffeomorphic to $S^1$.

**Update.**

Let us prove that $H_1$ is a surjective submersion. By the above considerations the same is true for $H_2$ because $M$ is symmetric in the variables $p, v$. Alternatively one can modify the $H_1$-proof in the obvious way.

1. $H_1$ is surjective with fibers diffeomorphic to $S^1$.

Let us first rewrite $(1)$ in a convenient form. We have $T_p S^2 = \{ v \in \mathbb R^3 \mid p \cdot v = 0 \} = p^\bot = $ orthogonal complement of the $1$-dimensional subspace spanned by $p$. Let $S^1_p$ denote the unit circle in $T_pS^2$. Then
$$M = \bigcup_{p \in S^2}\{ p \} \times S^1_p .$$

This shows that $H_2 : M \to S^2$ is surjective with fibers $H_2^{-1}(p) = \{ p \} \times S^1_p$ which are diffeomorphic to $S^1$.

2. $H_1$ is submersion.

The tangent space $T_{(p,v)}M$ at $(p,v) \in M$ is given as
$\ker D_{(p,v)} G$. See Gross and Meinrenken Chapter 5.2.3 "Tangent Spaces of Submanifolds", p. 117. To compute it, we use the Jacobian
matrix of $G$ which is the $(3 \times 6)$-matrix

$$J_{(p,v)} G = \begin{pmatrix} 2p & 0 \\ v & p \\ 0  &2v \end{pmatrix}$$
Note that both of the above "vectorial" columns represent three "scalar" columns.

Let $a, b \in \mathbb  R^3$ and $a^t, b^t$ the corresponding column vectors. Then $(a,b) \in \ker D_{(p,v)} G$ iff
$$J_{(p,v)} G \cdot \begin{pmatrix} a^t \\ b^t \end{pmatrix} = 0 .$$
This gives the three equations

- $2p \cdot a = 0$
- $v \cdot a + p \cdot b = 0$
- $2v \cdot b = 0$

In other words
$$T_{(p,v)} M = \{ (a,b) \in \mathbb R^6 \mid p \cdot a = 0, v \cdot b = 0, v \cdot a + p \cdot b = 0 \}.$$

We have to analyze
$$T_{(p,v)}H_1  : T_{(p,v)}M  \to T_{H_1(p,v))}S^2 = T_p S^2 .$$

Let $\pi_1  : \mathbb R^6 \to \mathbb R^3$ be the projection onto the first $3$ coordinates. Then $D_{(p,v)}\pi_1 : T_{(p,v)}\mathbb R^6 = \mathbb R^6 \to \mathbb R^3 = T_p\mathbb R^3$ is nothing else than $\pi_1$ (this is true for all linear maps).

$T_{(p,v)}H_1$ is the restriction of $D_{(p,v)}\pi_1 = \pi_1$. Its kernel is therefore
$$\ker T_{(p,v)}H_1 = \{ (a,b) \in T_{(p,v)} M  \mid a = 0\} = \{ (0,b) \in \mathbb R^6 \mid v \cdot b = p \cdot b = 0  \} \\= \{0\} \times \operatorname{Span}(p, v)^\bot .$$

Here $\operatorname{Span}(p, v)$ denotes the linear subspace spanned by $p$ and $v$. Since $p \cdot v = 0$, this subspace is $2$-dimensional and its orthogonal complement in $\mathbb R^3$ is $1$-dimensional. The image of $T_{(p,v)}H_1$ is isomorphic to $T_{(p,v)}M / \ker T_{(p,v)}H_1$, thus it has dimension $2$ which means that $T_{(p,v)}H_1$ is surjective.

**Here is an alternative proof which shows that $H_1$ is a submersion.**

Given $(p,v) \in M$, the idea is to find an open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ in $S^2$ and a smooth map $\phi : U \to M$ such that $\phi(p) = (p,v)$ and $H_1 \circ \phi = i : U \hookrightarrow S^2$.  Then $T_{(p,v)}H_1 \circ T_p\phi = T_p i = id$ which shows that $T_{(p,v)}H_1$ must be surjective.

This requires to find a smooth map $g : U \to \mathbb R^3$ such that $g(p) = v$ and $g(q) \in S^1_q \subset T_qS^2$.

Since $p \cdot v = 0$, i.e. $p,v$ are linearly independent, we try the *Ansatz* $g(q)= a p + b v$ with $a, b \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$. Let us begin by taking $b = 1$ and weakening the requirement to $g(q) \in T_qS^2$. This means
$$q \cdot g(q) = a (q \cdot p) + q \cdot v =  0 $$
which is equivalent to
$$a = - \frac{q \cdot v}{q \cdot p}. $$
$a$ is well-defined on $V  = \{ q \in \mathbb R^3 \mid q \cdot p \ne 0\}$. This is an open neigborhood of $p$ in $\mathbb R^3$. Then indeed
$$\gamma : V \to \mathbb R^3, \gamma(q) = - \frac{q \cdot v}{q \cdot p}p + v$$
is a smooth map with $\gamma(q) \in T_qS^2$ for $q \in U = V \cap S^2$. Since $p$ and $v$ are linearly independent, we see that $\gamma(q) \ne 0$. Hence also

$$g : V \to \mathbb R^3, g(q) = \frac{\gamma(q)}{\lVert \gamma(q) \rVert}$$
is smooth and has the property $g(q) \in S^1_q$ for $q \in U$. Now we can take $\phi(q) = (q, g(q))$.

Comment: Is this correct: To show that $H_2$ is surjective, notice $M$ contains all unit vectors on $S^2$. Therefore, for every unit vector $v\in S^2$, there exists $p\in S^2$ such that $(p,v)\in M$. Hence, $H_2$ is surjective. To show $H_2$ is a submersion, we need to show that the differential $dH_2$ is surjective. Since $M$ is defined as the set of all $(p,v)\in TS^2$ such that $v.v=1$, then $T_(p,v)M$ consists of pairs $(u,w)$, where $u$ is a tangent vector to $S^2$ at $p$, and $w$ is a tangent vector to the unit sphere $T_pS^2$ at $v$…

Comment: … Since $v$ is a unit vector tangent to $S^2$ at $p$, the $w$ must be orthogonal to $v$. Now, $H_2(p,v)=v$. Define the differential of $H_2$, $dH_2:T_(p,v)M\rightarrow T_vS^2$ by $dH_2(u,w)=w$. We see that $dH_2$ is surjective (for any $w^\prime$ if we take $w=w^\prime$ and $u=0$.

Comment: @MrProf The phrase "$M$ contains all unit vectors on $S^2$" does not make sense. $M$ is a set of pairs $(p,v) \in S^2 \times S^2$. But given $v \in S^2$, take any $q \ne 0$ in the orthogonal complement $C_v \subset \mathbb R^3$ of $v$. Then $p = q/\lVert q \rVert$ has the property that $(p,v) \in M$ showing that $H_2$ is surjectve. Actually you see that $H_2^{-1}(v) = S^1_v \times \{v\}$, where $S^1_v$ is a the unit circle in the $2$-dimensional vector space $C_v$. The computation of $T_{(p,v)}M$ seems to be insufficiently substantiated.

Comment: The point of my answer was this: If you have proved that $H_1$ is a surjective submersion, then the same is true for $H_2$ simply because $M$ is symmetric in $p$ and $v$ (via the diffeomorphism $\psi$).

Comment: In the question, $M=\{(p,v)\in TS^2|v.v=1\}$. This made me conclude that $M$ contains all unit vectors on $S^2$. However, it appears to me that this is not the definition of $M$ you used in your solution. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: @MrProf $M$ is the set of **pairs** of unit vectors $(p,v) \in S^2 \times S^2$ such that $p \cdot v = 0$. Thus $M$ does not contain any unit vector on $S^2$ - simply because such a vector is no pair.

Comment: Now I see. It seems my prove of the surjectivity of $H_1$ may be wrong. Here is the proof: $M$ includes all unit tangent vectors at every point on $S^2$. That is, for any point $p\in S^2$, there is a unit tangent vector $v$ such that $(p,v)\in M$. Hence, $H_1$ is surjective. The differential of $H_1$ at any point $(p,v)$ simply projects out the $p$ component: it maps $T_(p,v)M$, which is 3-dimensional, to $T_pS^2$, which is 2-dimensional. The rank of the differential of $H_1$ is the dimension of $T_pS^2$ (i.e. 2). This means the differential has full rank. Hence …

Comment: … $H_1$ is a submersion. Lastly, the fiber of $H_1$ over a point $p\in S^2$ is the set of all $v$ such that $(p,v)\in M$, and $v$ is a unit tangent vector at $p$. Therefore, the fiber is the circle of all unit vectors in $T_pS^2$, which is diffeomorphic to $S^1$.

Comment: If my proof is wrong, could you please show me what to fix, or if you don’t mind, edit the solution you posted so it would include the proof that $H_1$ is surjective and is a submersion? Your help would be greatly appreciated.